# fetching html element id using jquery for ajax fetched content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

scenario :
I have list of cities populated in html select tag and on change of it
list of sub localities are fetched as html checkboxes .

on change of status of sublocality checkboxes , I want to get list of checked element's label  and value in separate arrays . so , that I can process those things for another functionality in document

problem : 
if the checkboxes were not dynamically fetched using ajax  I was able to get id of the checkboxes but not when it is fetched using ajax

the code used for the purpose is mentioned below,
any help is appreciated

```
var val = [],
    ids = [];
$("input[name='sublocality[]']:checked").each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'sublocality') {
        val.push($(this).next("span").text());
        ids.push($(this).val());
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

when any html element added dynamically to the DOM then you have to attach its parent element to trigger any event on this

```
var val = [],
ids = [];
$(document).find("input[name='sublocality[]']:checked").each(function(i)
{
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'sublocality') {
        val.push($(this).next("span").text());
        ids.push($(this).val());
    }
})
```

Like here i am attaching the document element to find the checkboxes and triggering events on that